# Android - call method instead of class - sdk

Tags: java, android, class, sdk

I have my main application class as follows and what I would like to know is how to change one line to call a method either from same class or another class, whilst the others still call activities.  Here is the code:

```
public class InfoActivity extends GDListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.info_activity_title);

    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this);
    adapter.add(createTextItem(R.string.info_about, AboutActivity.class));
    adapter.add(createTextItem(R.string.info_terms, TermsActivity.class));
    adapter.add(createTextItem(R.string.info_privacy, PrivacyActivity.class));

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private TextItem createTextItem(int stringId, Class<?> klass) {
    final TextItem textItem = new TextItem(getString(stringId));
    textItem.setTag(klass);
    return textItem;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final TextItem textItem = (TextItem) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(InfoActivity.this, (Class<?>) textItem.getTag());
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

The line in question:

```
adapter.add(createTextItem(R.string.info_about, AboutActivity.class));
```

I would like to call a method which as an example does this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { AboutActivity.this.getString(R.string.feedback_email) } );
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, AboutActivity.this.getString(R.string.feedback_subject)); 
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Right now I have this in the onCreate method of AboutActivity, but there naturally is no reason to have this functionality (sending email) within an activity.  Instead it can just be ran as is.  So, how could I do this?

Thanks!

The other two lines:

```
 adapter.add(createTextItem(R.string.info_terms, TermsActivity.class));
    adapter.add(createTextItem(R.string.info_privacy, PrivacyActivity.class));
```

they can remain the same in terms of functionality.  This question is an addendum from this one (which I asked earlier and got answered):

[Android - call method instead of class - sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939768/android-call-method-instead-of-class-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How ever you choose to go about this, the trick is to actually move the decision making about what to do when a particular item is clicked down into the `onListItemClick` method. Here's a simple approach. First, change your `createTextItem` method to this:

```
private TextItem createTextItem(int stringId) {
    final TextItem textItem = new TextItem(getString(stringId));
    return textItem;
}
```

Then, change your `onListItemClick` to this:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final TextItem textItem = (TextItem) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    String textItemContents = textItem.getString(); //I don't know if this is actually correct. I don't know what the TextItem class is. But I think you get the idea.
    Intent intent = getIntentForString(textItemContents);
    startActivity(Intent);
}
```

Your `getIntentForString()` method would then look something like this (note we can't use a switch because support for using switch statements with strings has only just recently been added to java):

```
private Intent getIntentForString(String textViewContents){
  if(textViewContents.equals(getString(R.string.info_about))){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { 
      AboutActivity.this.getString(R.string.feedback_email) } );
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
      AboutActivity.this.getString(R.string.feedback_subject)); 
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
    return emailIntent;
  }
  else if(textViewContents.equals(getString(R.string.info_terms)){
    return new Intent(InfoActivity.this, TermsActivity.class);
  }
  else if(textViewContents.equals(getString(R.string.info_privacy)){
    return new Intent(InfoActivity.this, Privacy.class);
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

Note this approach has a downfall though. If yous start adding a bunch of different items to your ListView you're going to need to grow and grow your `getIntentForString()` method. For right now though, this should suffice. If you find yourself adding more options to your ListView though they'll be a more complicated approach that we'll need to take.

Comment: Awesome stuff!  :-)  Could you give an example for getIntentForString() method.  I was thinking of a switch statement() and then for each case:  new Intent(InfoActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);  but if I wanted to call mail method - does it need to go in another class? or can I call a method from within same class  or simply create another  class but naturally one that doesn't inherit from activity (in this case GDListActivity).

Comment: Updated answer to address this.

Comment: That is great!  Thanks Kurtis!  Is there any way of leaving you more points?  I'm not sure how this site works.. I accepted answer..

Comment: BTW - thanks for letting me know about switch support (or lack of for strings). I was not aware of that and some of my other code I was starting to write switch statement for string comparison.. so you saved me time in that regard.

Comment: @SpacialWise once you get more reputation points, you'll be able to upvote my answers. So once you get more rep points, feel free to come back and vote up my answers :)

Comment: @SpacialWise I upvoted your questions. You now have 15 rep points which means you can upvote answers :)

Comment: That's awesome! :-)  Cheers.  I'm going to upvote both answers, as they have assisted me greatly in understanding android development.

Comment: Yea :( That's how the site works. That said, your questions so far have been well asked (hence why I was able to answer them in such a detailed fashion). We like users like you :) So come back and ask more questions so I can answer them and get more rep :) (but don't take that as license to ask about every little problem you have, there's something to be said for self-learning, just come here for the big stuff, or when you really get stuck).

Comment: Yes definitely..  I currently have three Android books open next to me and I'm reading them, trying things out and this is the first BIG question where I've really got stumped.  I won't be asking about anything, but mainly learning about best practices etc. and improvements as I go along.  One last thing - in my other question I posted the code I implemented which you gave me and wanted your opinion.  It works as expected, but a senior perspective or tips is always a good way to learn about pitfalls etc.  I pasted in the body of my original question at the bottom.